# Want a reqular expression to parse an email reply with ↵ character

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Want to parse just the latest reply from the below email thread. i.e **Hello Nikhil Bopora,↵↵Just to give a brief, I am in process of building an
alternate e-lending↵platform.**

The general regex that I wrote to cover varied use cases  `/[\s]*([\s\S]*.)[\s]*\n\n[\s]*On [\s\S]*.<[\s\S]*.> wrote/`
is not not working on ↵ character.

Can someone help me write a good regular expression in javascript to parse this.

> Hello Nikhil,↵↵Just to give a brief, I am in process of building an
>   alternate e-lending↵platform.↵↵↵On Sun, Jan 10, 2016 at 1:16 PM,
>   Deepak Modak ↵wrote:↵↵> *Deepak Modak has
>   sent a message*↵>↵> I am trying to build a financial product, need
>   your feedback & insights.↵>↵> Requested TimeSlots:↵>
>   --------------------------↵> *Mon Jan 11 2016, 10:00 PM*↵>↵>↵>

Comment: don't know why the enter symbol was not converted to **\n** while the mail was sent. It came from gmail.

Comment: Wow 2 upvotes for question that can be solved by a simple search?

Answer (score 1):

To try to give a short answer to this, here it is a single regex that should work for you without any replacement.  \u21b5 represents the "↵" and makes this possible.  If you want to get rid of the arrows later, just do a separate search with /\u21b5/ pattern and replace with a space, as I have done in previous answer.

```
/((.|\u21b5)+?)(?:On\s+[A-Z]{3},\s+[A-Z]{3}\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d|$)/i
```

Added information:

I'll try to leave this alone after this last edit, but below is what I believe is a significant improvement on the last pattern.  The below pattern can also stand on its own (doesn't require replacement), but the improvement (I believe) is that there are no capturing groups.  The match that is returned should show exactly what is being sought; there is need to pull out the submatch, as in the last example.  This was done by using the positive lookahead.  Please let me know if there would have been a better way for me to convey this (e.g. in a comment).

```
/(?:(?:.|\u21b5)+?)(?=(?:On\s+[A-Z]{3},\s+[A-Z]{3}\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d|$))/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a single clean RegEx, but I was able to get this to work.  I did this in two steps, first removing the Unicode character (I would guess that you don't want to see those arrows in your results anyway).  Maybe the RegEx alone is all you wanted, but I'm providing all of the code to hopefully make more clear what I've done.  One thing I noticed is that the first date in your string above has commas in the date where the second date in the string does not. I assume that this is exactly how the emails will continue to come in, but if not, you can adjust the RegEx accordingly.  I hope this helps.

```
   <script>
       "use strict";
         var patt = /()/;
         var myString = "";
         var match=[];

            myString = "Hello Nikhil,↵↵Just to give a brief, I am in process of building an alternate e-lending↵platform.↵↵↵On Sun, Jan 10, 2016 at 1:16 PM, Deepak Modak ↵wrote:↵↵> Deepak Modak has sent a message↵>↵> I am trying to build a financial product, need your feedback & insights.↵>↵> Requested TimeSlots:↵> --------------------------↵> Mon Jan 11 2016, 10:00 PM↵>↵>↵>";

         //for the replace regex, using the required 4 hexadecimal digits "21b5" that represent the unicode character "downwards arrow with corner leftwards"
            patt = /\u21b5/g;
         //replacing arrow with empty space
            myString = myString.replace(patt," ");

         //resetting the pattern. I added a pipe (or) to account for the possibility that the email is not a reply. Looking for "On Sun, Jan 10, 2016 at 1" or similar pattern to represent start of end of captured group of interest.

            patt = /(.+?)(?:On\s+[A-Z]{3},\s+[A-Z]{3}\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d|$)/i;

            match = patt.exec(myString);

            console.log("The submatch: " + match[1]);

    </script>
```